# WPF UI size, pixel vs .png pixel

Tags: c#, wpf, png

I was given UI design for project. This design is made by Photoshop. In this design every UI element's (button, textbox, listbox, etc) height and width are given in pixels. I am following that design while making user interface in WPF.
But, even I do exactly what is given UI design, image and my UI are not same. It seems WPF pixel is not same as Photoshop pixel(I know it is nonsense). Window, Button, TextBox, etc, sizes are more bigger than they are in .png picture.

Is there something am I missing?

Thank You

Comment: "I know it is nonsense" Not exactly. WPF uses ["device independent pixels"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx) (go to the *About Resolution and Device-Independent Graphics* section of that article) that aren't identical to the physical pixels of your monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF does not operate in pixels, it operates in device-independent units, which might or might not equal to 1 physical pixel, depending on your monitor and OS settings.

Without seeing your actual UI its hard to tell what do you mean by "image and my UI are not same". There are a couple things you could try though. First, if you experience blur when rendering shapes or images - try setting either `UseLayoutRounding` or `SnapToDevicePixels` to `True`. Second, if you feel that the distance between different elements is larger than it should be - make sure that you account for non-zero `Margin`-s and `Padding`-s (some controls have those by default), when building your layout.

If nothing helps, try using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It will allow you to inspect your UI while your application is running, and among other things it will tell you the exact size of any element and, more importantly, why it has that size.